# Login issue using dokan and revo wp theme

Tags: wordpress, authentication, vendor, dokan

i installed dokan multi vendor plugin and revo theme on wordpress, whenever i use the multi-vendor account to login using the login widget, it takes to me the customer dashboard.
but on the regular login [page](https://agurung.com/my-account) ,it takes me to the correct url

I tried placing this code in themes/functions.php but didn't help, Pls I need assistance

add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'ckc_login_redirect', 10, 2 );

function ckc_login_redirect( $redirect_url, $user ) {
    // Change this to the url to Updates page

```
if( $user->roles[0] == 'seller' ) {
    return dokan_get_navigation_url(‘dashboard’);   
}
```

return $redirect_url;
}

Answer (score 2):

As you are not using the WooCommerce default my-account page for that reason, your vendor is not redirecting to the Dashboard page. I beleive that your theme login widget is using the default WordPress login function. So, I will suggest you to follow this function reference to redirect vendor to dashboard-https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect

Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you this reply I tried this and put  it in my themes/functions.php but it didn't work.pls  is this wrong      function custom_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
  if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
    if( in_array('seller', $user->roles)) {
      $redirect_to = home_url(). '/dashboard';
      return $redirect_to;
    } else {
      return home_url();
    }
  } else {
      return home_url();
  }
}
 
add_filter('login_redirect', 'custom_login_redirect', 10, 3);